# Manifest V3 - import class in the service_worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

im trying to import a class in my service worker, in my Chrome Extension

So this is what I have at the beginning of the file :

```
/*global chrome*/
try {
    importScripts("utils/utils.js");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

and this is the function where I call the class :

```
async function injectPopup() {
    try {
        let b = new Utils();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

the **console.log** is printing me this :

```
ReferenceError: Utils is not defined
    at injectPopup (<anonymous>:4:17)
    at <anonymous>:28:3
```

this is the content of **utils/utils.js** :

```
class utils {
    test() {
        console.log("foooo");
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how am I supposed to call the classes ? the goal is to have a cleaner code with and not all the logic in the same service_worker, so if there is another better practice I would love to know

Thanks !

Comment: Typo: `class utils` should be `class Utils`. Also, the visibility of your class is limited to the try{} block, so you'll need `globalThis.Utils = class Utils { .... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case there were two problems :

First, as **wOxxOm** commented, I needed to create a global variable in the  service_worker file :

```
/*global chrome*/
let globals = {}; // HERE
try {
    importScripts("utils/Utils.js");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

And in the class declaration to add it to the global like this :

```
globals.Utils = class Utils {
    test() {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}
```

The second problem was that I was calling it from a function given to **chrome.scripting.executeScript** which cannot work, because the script is executed by itself in the given tab Javascript and **not** in the popup Javascript, and this is why the class could not be found.